# unspecified dimension of array initialisation with {}

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I am wondering if:

`int a[] = {1, 2};`

allocates sizeof(int) * number of constants inside brackets

`int a[5] = {1, 2};`

assigns constants to array fields from 0 to 1 and then fills with 0

`int a[5] = {};`

fills with 0

What happens when I do:

`int a[] = {};`

Thanks.

Comment: Does it allocates any memory or just makes constant pointer? Where is that pointer pointing to (array constant pointer is pointer to itself)? So it allocates 1 int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int a[5] = {};
```

and

```
 int a[] = {};
```

are not valid C definitions.

In GNU C (C with gcc extensions), you can use empty `{}` and it is considered the same as `{0}`.

Note that `int []` is a incomplete type. When initializing an array of an incomplete type with explicit initializers, the type is completed and the number of elements of the array is then the number of elements in the brace enclosed initializer list.

So `int a[] =  {0};` defines an array of 1 element in C and in GNU C `int a[] =  {};` does the same.

Comment: What is the difference between a[5] = {0} and a[5] = {}? In first one you have 1 constant and rest is filled with zeros, in another you have zero constants and rest is filled with zeros. By what rule that is invalid? I was looking through K&R and C ISO, but I couldn't find.

Comment: @Deximat, it is invalid because the standard doesn't allow empty initializers, as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks, for the fast answers!